# Emacs 24.3 dired+ won't load

Tags: emacs, dired

I installed dired+ through list-packages (the folder was put in the elpa folder), and put `'(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")'` in my *init* file (which I created myself), and `'(require 'dired+)` under. When I open emacs, I get an error telling me there's an error in my *init* file. If I remove the `'(require 'dired+)` line, the error stops, but again dired+ doesn't work when I call dired mode. The actual folder that was downloaded when I installed it is `'dired+-20130206.1702'`. So I tried `'(require dired+-20130206.1702)`, which again gave me an error on startup.

I'm at my wits end. I've tried everything I can think of, gone through the GNU emacs docs, googled the problem, looked at the answers here at Stack, and no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say for certain without seeing all the code, but you appear to be quoting your forms for no reason.

i.e., these:

```
'(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
'(require 'dired+)
```

should be:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/")
(require 'dired+)
```

However that should just make them ineffectual, rather than causing errors directly.

Show us the code and the error message.

Edit:

> Adding the /dired+/ to the end seemed to fix it ... Although I have no idea why. Any thoughts?

`load-path` holds a list of directories in which Emacs will look for libraries. It does not automatically descend into sub-directories, so you need to specify all relevant directories for your libraries. Your dired+ library is clearly in the `~/.emacs.d/elpa/dired+/` directory.

For menubarplus, you will similarly need to check to see which directory the library is in.

To be honest, I had thought that the package management in Emacs 24 would take care of this automatically; but as I've not been using it, I'm not certain.

Edit 2:

Yes, I suspect you have some other problem here. I just experimented with installing a library via the package manager (albeit from the default package repository, which doesn't include a dired+ package), and after restarting Emacs `load-path` contained the path for the new library without any intervention on my part.

Comment: Sorry, the quotes were accidental. The code is EXACTLY as you have it, and the error message(s) are: Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `c:/Documents and Settings/Chris Kavanagh/Application Data/.emacs.d/init.el': and File error: Cannot open load file, dired+

Comment: I've tried this with several other packages, and every time I put in the (Require 'package), I get the same error(s). Really frustrating.

Comment: Somehow I stumbled across the FIX. Instead of (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/"), I put (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/dired+/"). Adding the /dired+/ to the end seemed to fix it. (and of course (require 'dired+))  Although I have no idea why. Any thoughts?

Comment: I tried this 'fix' with menubar-plus, and it didn't work. I got the same error, File error: Cannot open load file, menubarplus. . .My code is, (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/menubarplus") (require 'menubarplus). . .If anyone has any ideas, I'm listening.

Comment: Thanks for the help phils, it's much appreciated. . .Update: Now, dired+ quit working altogether. It won't open even if I use a dirdp command (as it did before). I changed NOTHING in the init file. Although I did add python-mode, and it seems to be working fine. Funny thing is, python-mode file(s) are in the .emacs folder, NOT in the elpa folder. The code in init is (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/python-mode.el") (require 'python-mode), YET it still works. .I'll keep playing with it to see if I can get it to work. Thanks again. If you have any ideas, I'll be checking here.

Comment: I figured out why dired+ wouldn't open & corrected (stupid error on my part). .However, I tried installing menu-bar+ manually (can't find it in list-packages) & it won't work. I get the same file error when I open emacs, file error: cannot open menu-bar+. I included (eval-after-load "menu-bar" '(require 'menubar+)) per directions. I tried using the same code as with dired+ & no luck. . .Lol, very frustrating.

Comment: And the menu-bar+.el (or .elc) file is in a directory which has been added to your `load-path`?

Comment: FYI, for libraries which aren't handled by a package manager, you typically want to have a sub-directory under ~/.emacs.d/ such as `~/.emacs.d/lisp/`; and then you would put `(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp"))` into your .emacs file so that you could subsequently load or `require` any of the `*.el` and `*.elc` files which you have put in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think Phils answered your question wrt loading **Dired+** (specify the right directory, the one where you put `dired+.el`).

Wrt **Menu-bar+**, the feature name is `menu-bar+`, not `menubarplus` and not `menu-barplus`. So change your `(require 'menubarplus)` to `(require 'menu-bar+)`.